# Wix Installer ASP.NET Core Separate Solution

Tags: asp.net-core, wix

I am trying to create installer via WIX TOOLSET, and all the guide/example that I found are creating a WIX project in same solution where the actual project is located.

But I want to create a separate Installer Solution that can refer ASP.NET Core App in another Solution.

Any example or article, where I can get some pointer will be extremely helpful.

**Update:**

By Manually updating `*.wixproj` and adding reference to project file I was able to accomplish this.

```
<ItemGroup>
<ProjectReference Include="C:\Users\posto\source\repos\HelloWorldSol\HelloWorldApp\HelloWorldApp.csproj">
  <Name>RefHelloWorldApp</Name>
  <Project>{57E314CF-2957-4FD2-8014-554DF345B0F8}</Project>
  <Private>True</Private>
  <DoNotHarvest>True</DoNotHarvest>
  <RefProjectOutputGroups>Binaries;Content;Satellites</RefProjectOutputGroups>
  <RefTargetDir>INSTALLFOLDER</RefTargetDir>
</ProjectReference>
```

although it requires the same manual update every time we add new `dll` reference.

Comment: It's been a really long time since I've done this with WiX, so I'm not putting as an answer in case I'm wrong. I don't think you can reference projects in another solution (or if you can I don't know how), but you should be able to re-reference any projects in a parallel solution for building the installer.

Comment: @BendertheGreatest thanks for your comment, That is a possible approach.

Comment: *Not sure why down voting ? is it not possible, not good practice or too basic ?*

Comment: I'm not the one who downvoted, but why can't you just maintain a second solution and add any relevant projects to it?

Comment: @BendertheGreatest, I am sure that you have't down-voted; you already provided one approach to solve this issue, 
That's why I have added a separate comment.
Yes, I am trying to add Projects as Reference in the Solution where installer project is.

Comment: I'm just thinking there may be a better approach than this. What problem are you trying to solve by having the `.wixproj` as part of a different solution than your other projects?

Comment: I assume that since you want to use WiX you want to run this on Windows.  How do you want to host the web application?  IIS?   Self hosting EXE / Windows Service?

Comment: @BendertheGreatest, No problem if I keep the WIX project in the Solution.
I just wanted to Keep Packaging and Deployment stuff in separate solution. Actually I already have 3 solution ( 1 Master actual core projects, 1 Worker Service for pulling stuff and 1 Add-On dll stuff )
I could keep this WIX project to Master solution but keeping it separate will reduce the complexity as well.

Comment: @ChristopherPainter, Yes I need to create a Website (app pool included) in IIS and also need to create a Windows Service.
As off now I was using GUI based Power shell scripts for the same.

Answer (score 1):

I maintain an FOSS WiX authoring tool called IsWiX.  Read the Web Application tutorial here.

https://github.com/iswix-llc/iswix-tutorials

ASP.NET Core is very similiar to ASP.NET with a few changes.

1) Use the IsWiX Bootstrapper Solution for WiX v3 project template instead of the IsWiX Solution for WiX v3.

2) In the bootstrapper project Bundle.wxs file add a line to install the DotNetCore hosting package.  Here is an example, a newer version is probably available.

```
<ExePackage Id="DotNetCore205WindowsHosting" SourceFile="Prereqs\DotNetCore.2.0.5-WindowsHosting.exe" InstallCommand="/q /norestart" Cache="no" Permanent="yes"/>
```

Some more information is available here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/publish-to-iis?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio